# Mention Friend in facebook status update

Tags: android, facebook, tagging

I want to mention(not tagging) a friend in fb status update using fb sdk.
I am able to tag friend using

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.put("tags","friend ids");
bundle.put("place","xxxxxx")
```

then send request and send bundle as params.

Any suggestions?